Django: Unable to display colors of linked products
I'm having trouble displaying the colors of linked products in my Django template. I have a Product model with a many-to-many relationship with a Color model, and I want to display the colors of the linked products.
Here is my view:
def product_varient_detail_view(request, pid):
    # ...
    colors = []
    linked_colors = []

    if product_variant.color.exists():
        colors = product_variant.color.all()

    if product_variant.color.exists():
        for color in product_variant.color.all():
            for linked_product in color.product_varients.all():
                if linked_product != product_variant:
                    linked_colors.extend(linked_product.color.all())

    context = {
        # ...
        'colors': colors,
        'linked_colors': linked_colors,
    }
    return render(request, "core/product_varient_detail.html", context)

And here is my template:
{% if colors %}
    {% for c in colors %}
        <div class="color__radio">
            <input type="radio" id="color_{{ c.id }}" name="color" 
                   data-image-url="{{ c.image.url }}" 
                   class="color-input" 
                   data-url="{% url 'core:product_varient_detail' c.product_varients.first.pid %}?color={{ c.coid }}">
            <label class="color__radio-label" 
                   for="color_{{ c.id }}" 
                   style="background-color: {{ c.code }};"></label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if linked_colors %}
    {% for c in linked_colors %}
        <div class="color__radio">
            <input type="radio" id="color_{{ c.id }}" name="color" 
                   data-image-url="{{ c.image.url }}" 
                   class="color-input" 
                   data-url="{% url 'core:product_varient_detail' c.product_varients.first.pid %}?color={{ c.coid }}">
            <label class="color__radio-label" 
                   for="color_{{ c.id }}" 
                   style="background-color: {{ c.code }};"></label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

However, the colors of the linked products are not being displayed. I've tried debugging the code, but I'm not sure what's going wrong. Can anyone help me figure out the issue?
Models:

class Color(models.Model):
    # ...
    product_varients = models.ManyToManyField('Product', related_name='color_variants', blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    pid=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="prd",alphabet="abcdef")


    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    cagtegory=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True,related_name="category")
    color=models.ManyToManyField(Color,blank=True)


I adjusted the logic in your product_varient_detail_view to ensure that all unique colors from linked products are gathered correctly without duplication.
def product_varient_detail_view(request, pid):
    product_variant = get_object_or_404(Product, pid=pid)  # Adjust according to your actual model

    colors = product_variant.color.all()

    # Create a set to avoid duplicate linked colors
    linked_colors = set()

    for color in colors:
        for linked_product in color.product_varients.exclude(id=product_variant.id):
            linked_colors.update(linked_product.color.all())

    linked_colors = list(linked_colors)

    context = {
        'colors': colors,
        'linked_colors': linked_colors,
    }
    return render(request, "core/product_varient_detail.html", context)

Here's the template code to display both the colors of the selected product variant and the linked colors.
{% if colors %}
    <h3>Available Colors</h3>
    {% for c in colors %}
        <div class="color__radio">
            <input type="radio" id="color_{{ c.id }}" name="color" 
                   data-image-url="{{ c.image.url }}" 
                   class="color-input" 
                   data-url="{% url 'core:product_varient_detail' c.product_varients.first.pid %}?color={{ c.coid }}">
            <label class="color__radio-label" 
                   for="color_{{ c.id }}" 
                   style="background-color: {{ c.code }};"></label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if linked_colors %}
    <h3>Linked Product Colors</h3>
    {% for c in linked_colors %}
        <div class="color__radio">
            <input type="radio" id="linked_color_{{ c.id }}" name="linked_color" 
                   data-image-url="{{ c.image.url }}" 
                   class="color-input" 
                   data-url="{% url 'core:product_varient_detail' c.product_varients.first.pid %}?color={{ c.coid }}">
            <label class="color__radio-label" 
                   for="linked_color_{{ c.id }}" 
                   style="background-color: {{ c.code }};"></label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

I hope this will help you a little.

This is working but a new problem occured please see my this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79096879/issue-displaying-all-colors-of-a-product-variant-in-django-template
